# ASP.NET cannot resolve user hostname in azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have written an ASP.net website that gets the machine name from the person browsing the website using

```
sName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.UserHostAddress).HostName.ToString
```

If I publish this to a web server on our local network, it works fine.

We also have an Azure server and I want to publish it to that server, but it does not return the machine name. We have the Azure server connected to our local network via a permanent tunnel.

I'm assuming that the code can't resolve the name as it can access the DNS on the network. Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the `Request.UserHostAddress`? Is it a private address as you expect, or a public IP? Do you know what name server is being targeted for the search?

Comment: locally i am getting it yes, but not on the azure server. it is the address i expect. im not sure how i could tell which name server is being targetted. we do not have a domain, or DNS server onsite. the meraki firewall handles DHCP

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Our  app will not work with Azure DNS Private Zones automatically. To work with ***Azure DNS Private Zones*** we need to add the below  in app settings:

```
WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER with value 168.63.129.16

WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL with value 1
```

For more information please refer this [***MS Q&A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/85359/azure-app-service-unable-to-resolve-hostname-of-vi.html) as suggested by @ [***didier3001***](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/25115/didier3001.html)

And this for use [***`Dns.GetHostEntry Method`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=net-6.0)

Comment: hi,thanks for this but its not a web app, is a website running on IIS on my VM. Will this still work?

Comment: AFAIK, It should work . But i did not tried on vm.

Comment: where exactly would i put these settings?

Comment: Could you please MS DOC:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-getstarted-portal